# Why is photo not displayed using <img>?

Tags: html, image

I am creating a div of text and image so they are side by side. When I use the  tag the photo will not display. This is a photo I took with my camera. It is high resolution; still, that shouldn't matter. When I try other photo files in its place, they work fine. Another strange thing is that other photos from that same group do not work (ex. me1.jpg, me2.jpg). I have tried "../images/People/me4.jpg" and "/images/People/me4.jpg" to no avail. Thx for help.

```
 <article>
   <section>
     <img src="images/People/me4.jpg" />
     <p> this is some sampel text about peole 
     and blah the ateh te as;ldk aldjfs al;sdk
     a;slkd asd;ljfa;lsjd a;dljfa dkfei teh ie
     </p>

   </section>
</article>
```

---

```
 article {
 width: 440px;
 padding-left: 20px;
 }

section {
width: 430px;
background: white;
}

section > img {
float: left;
width: 170px;
height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: You use "file protocol" or "http protocol" in your page?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem may be either in the "CSS" (for you have only posted a part of CSS is not possible to detect), as the "path" of the file (which is more likely), I recommend:

### Differences between HTTP and FILE

First you must learn the differences between ["http protocol"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) and ["file protocol"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme).

### HTTP protocol:

HTTP functions as a request-response protocol in the client-server computing model. A web browser, for example, may be the client and an application running on a computer hosting a web site may be the server. The client submits an HTTP request message to the server. The server, which provides resources such as HTML files and other content, or performs other functions on behalf of the client, returns a response message to the client. The response contains completion status information about the request and may also contain requested content in its message body.

### File protocol:

The file URI scheme is a URI scheme specified in RFC 1630 and RFC 1738, typically used to retrieve files from within one's own computer.

### Developer tools

Second, your need learn about "Developer tools" (network tab), with developer tools you can detect "path" from your image and problems in "CSS" (if is your problem).

Using developer tools from Chrome (like Webkit):

https://developer.chrome.com/devtools#improving-network-performance

example:
[image: network chrome]

Using from Firefox:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor

Example:
[image: network firefox]

I recommend that if you are developing your "html" for future use in a website/homepage, always use "http", good examples of "http" to use on your machine:

- http://www.wampserver.com/en/ (windows, apache, php, mysql)
- https://www.apachefriends.org/ (cross-platform, apache, php, mysql, pearl)
- http://nodejs.org/ (javascript for network, async server :) )
- http://fatfreeframework.com/home (framework php, no need apache in "developer")
- https://www.djangoproject.com/ (python + web framework)

Comment: Awesome answer it is!!

Answer (score 0):

First try placing the image in the same folder where the HTML is . and just use

```
 <img src="me4.jpg" />
```

if you see the image on the HTML page then paste the image file to its original folder back and then right lick on the image to copy the exact location of the image file and paste it in the src of the image in img tag
as

```
 <img src="d:/folder/new/me4.jpg" />
```

there might be a problem with the source location of the image

Comment: <img src="me4.jpg" /> didn't work; something must be up with the photos or the filepath; i don't know but i'm not spending anymore time on it

Comment: your photo must be corrupted then using some other file